About differentiation of supernumber-valued functionals
I'm (trying) to read deWitt's A Global Approach to Quantum Field Theory and trying to get around the first definitions. The central object is a differentiable functional $F: \Phi \rightarrow \Lambda_{\infty}$ where $\Phi$ is a space of sections of some bundle over a manifold $M$ and $\Lambda_{\infty}$ denotes the set of supernumbers. Such a differentiable functional is characterized by the existence of like functions (either actual functions or "the formal values of distributions")$_{i,}F$ and $F_{,i}$ such that $$\delta F[\phi]=\int_M\delta\phi^i (x)(_{i,}F)[\phi]=\int_M(F_{,i})[\phi]\delta\phi^i$$
Where the $\delta F$ is the variation induced on the functional in varying $\phi$ by $\delta \phi$. Additionally charts have been chosen to perform the integration (carried over on the whole base manifold by a suitable partition of unity), and the summation convention is being used. The space of variations is $C^{\infty}$ with compact support.
The problem I'm trying to understand is the following. Suppose $F$ is pure for all $\phi$, that is, it is either a linear combination of even products of generators (commutative with everything in the algebra) or a linear combination of odd products of generators (anticommuting between themselves). Then, $$_{,i}F=(-1)^{i(F+1)} F_{,i}$$
where the convention is that $i,F$ are zero if the correspondent quantity is commutative (in the case of $i$, the $\phi^i$) or $1$ otherwise. I have tried multiplying the variation in $F$ by an anticommuting number, passing it inside the integral and trying to switch things around in order to equate both left and right functional differentiations, "fundamental lemma of variations" style, which I assume can be made to work here. But I arrive at the problem that I don't know what type of supernumber are the functional derivatives of $F$. Are they of the same type as $F$? If so, how could I go about doing that? I tried to use the definition of even and odd supernumbers, but I don't know the "formal infinite series" being used interacts with integration.

The conventions and terminology physicists vs. mathematicians use here are different enough that I'm guessing you'll get better answers to this question on physics.SE instead: https://physics.stackexchange.com/
